# Scrape Facebook Insights with R

Tags: facebook, r

I'm an admin for a number of Facebook pages and would like to build some code in R for pulling data from the Insights page for each and drop it onto my computer.  Is there a good way to do that with R?

Example: The page I want to scrape from is:

`https://www.facebook.com/[Group Name]?sk=insights`
and I want to pull the Total Page Likes from it, so I'd want to be able to scrape the "1,365" inside the: `<div data-reactid=".r[3z4an].[1].[0].[1].[0].[0].[1].[0].[0].[0]" class="_50f6 _50f7 _5tfx">1,365</div>` tag and put it in a data frame.

Comment: Use the R package [Rfacebook](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rfacebook/).

Comment: @Ramnath I've been trying to get it to work that way and have followed all of the steps to make it work and it doesn't appear to work for what I want it to do.

Comment: @CoreyChristensen is right. With Rfacebook you can get access to pages with getPage but you cannot (or I was not able to) get access to that pages insights. If it can help: insights are not public, they need you to be admin of the page. I am trying to do the same thing but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

There is the getInsights method. Usage:

```
getInsights(object_id, token, metric, period = "day", parms = NA, version = 2.3, n = 5)
```

Check the documentation for more details [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rfacebook/Rfacebook.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

Happy parsing!

```
call_insights <- function(your_page_id,access_token){
        fromJSON(
            sprintf('https://graph.facebook.com/%s/?fields=insights{name,values},likes&access_token=%s',your_page_id,access_token)
        )
    }
```